# Consume protobuf messages from Graphite

Tags: protocol-buffers, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'd like to know if I can send data to Graphite using protobuf.

I have an application that sends statistics in protobuf format and I want to start sending those statistics to Graphite.

I searched in google and I just found this https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=protobuf&check_keywords=yes&area=default# but it's not clear if it's only for graphite internal core usage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, think it is available since version 1.x and up.

See for an example in Python:
 https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/examples/example-protobuf-client.py

You will have to enable the listener in the Carbon configuration:
https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/conf/carbon.conf.example#L113-L117